# bringing order to my wallet

Tags: single-word-requests

I try to bring order to my wallet, throw away unnecessary business cards and notes that piled up over the years. This isn't very complicated. Yet I is surprisingly complicated to find a verb to desrcibe this task in English. I search in a few dictionaries and tried to google sentences with the words I found, but none of them seems to be common enough to be the right verb...

Comment: Are you trying to _organize_ your wallet?

Comment: There are lots of self-help books to help you *declutter* your house or your life. It sounds like you are decluttering your wallet.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are *[culling](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=cull)* your wallet

> To remove rejected members or parts from (a herd, for example).

*American Heritage Dictionary*